# Chrome Extension | javascript file manipulation at run time on button click in popup.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I’m working on a chrome extension where I’d like to update one javascript file at runtime on button click in popup.html

Can anyone tell me is there any possibility manipulate javascript file at rutime with a button click?

For example: Javascript file want to manipulate named index.js, containing only one array object as following :

```
let obj1 = [
  { Name: "Peter", Dep: "Team1" }, 
  { Name: "Abhilasha", Dep: "Team2" }
]
```

New object to be added/pushed to the file index.js :

```
{ Name: "Ani", Dep: "Team3" }
```

On clicking the button on extension popup it will update the index.js with the new object and resultant array object in the index.js is as follow:

```
let obj1 = [
  { Name: "Peter", Dep: "Team1" }, 
  { Name: "Abhilasha", Dep: "Team2" }, 
  { Name: "Ani", Dep: "Team3" }
]
```

I am not sure whether file manipulation is possible from front-end using onClick event. It would be really helpful if you guys can guide me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) Changing the script's text won't change the current value. 2) Is the code you want to change a part of the web page or your popup page? If it's a web page, show us the context where it's defined e.g. is it inside a function.

Comment: All you need is to use `push()` to affect the array in memory - or is this some attempt at using a JS file as a datastore for all other users too? If you're attempting the latter then this is not going to work. Use a server side database/blob storage instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm, the file index.js I want to modify, is not part of my web page. This index.j s file act as datastore which is access by background.js. It is accessing the obj1 and based on the match object it is executing some content script. Now I am checking the case how to handle new user. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan,I have tried with obj.push(newObj) but, it's not actually updating the object permanently and not able to insert the block of newObj in the file. And yes this JS file is used as a data store, where I want to update the datastore on button click. Thanks a lot for you reply.

Comment: You can't modify files in the extension. Use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to store the values.